# Recover SO account after google email was deleted

Tags: support, merge-accounts, account-recovery

I [deleted my google account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32046) a few months ago. And I can't restore deleted email.

How can I restore or merge my old SO account with the new one?

Comment: If you still have access to the account (if you are logged in) you might be able to add an other openid provider yourself.

Comment: @johannes-kuhn I don't have access to the account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) link at the bottom of the page and under *What can we help you with*, Select *I need to merge user profiles*.

Fill in the other details and Submit. A stackexchange employee will attend to you soon.

Screenshot

[image: Contact us]

Comment: I've submitted my problem. Thanks.